# Was this movie the first usage of screen projection?

Tags: film-techniques, forbidden-planet

"The Forbidden Planet" came out in 1956, and there is a particular visual effects shot in the movie that was ground breaking at the time. Projecting live action onto a painted background, and I've always thought this was the first usage of this VFX technique in a motion picture. Particularly the way it was done, which I'm not sure how it was done, but I think it involved filming the live action with a painted glass plate as the background.

Here are the shots I'm referring to:

[image: screen capture from The Forbidden Planet]

[image: screen capture from The Forbidden Planet]

[I found an interesting blog on the matte paints done for The Forbidden Planet](http://nzpetesmatteshot.blogspot.ca/2011/03/forbidden-planet-shakespeare-in-space.html). With some amazing work in progress shots of those scenes. I hadn't seen these before.

That article does point out on interesting point about one of those shots, and that was a MOVING CAMERA. I think this is what I was looking for, and might be the first time a moving camera was integrated with a live action matte painting effect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had to watch *Forbidden Planet* again, and the mattes you reference are indeed combined with moving, live-action shots and enhanced with animated effects.  I know that *The Wizard of Oz* predates *Forbidden Planet* by 17 years - and *Metropolis* predates it by 30 years.

Your link (and several others I followed) turned out to be quite fascinating and enlightening.

Ultimately though, I think the first use of rear projected matte paintings was by Georges Melies in his films from 1902 - 1904.

You can read more about his techniques [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georges_M%C3%A9li%C3%A8s).

That said, if you are specifically looking for a film that includes a **moving** matte combined with live-action, then [*The Prodigal*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0048517/) was released a year earlier in 1955.

One particular shot involves a large matte painting that is combined with a slow pan right to left and ends up in the bedroom of Lana Turner, all the while including live action plates that have been rear-projected into the scene.

[image]

Comment: I remember watching a documentary on the history of visual effects, and in it, I thought it mentioned that The Forbidden Planet used a new type of matte painting that was developed by Disney. This new technique would become mainstream well into the late 1980's, as it solved a lot of the problems associated with the techniques used in the films you stated. Sadly, that's all I remember. I have tried to google more about it but can't find any clear answer.

Comment: I think I recall that same documentary - it also went on to describe how the Disney animators created the 'ID' monster and added all the other effects like the rocket engines etc. perhaps I am barking up the wrong tree - I'll dig around...

Comment: Although not the earliest I thought the use of rear projection for the plane crash into ocean in Hitchcock's Foreign Correspondent was very clever: http://www.hitchcockwiki.com/blog/?cat=101

Comment: I think the 1920s Ben Hur used a traveling matte effect to overlay live actors on footage of the collapsing Senate model.